# how to common data entry from whole application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC in my application I have one _layoutPage that is like master page for all application

and other then views are there who handle data entry section & gridview section both commonly

Now I want to move DateEntry section as commonly for all application

How can I do this ?
[image]

one layout is common for header , navigation , footer , body  now i want to make two part of body in which 
1. Data Entry header section - common 
2. Data entry section        - dynamic 
3. Data entry footer section - common

Comment: You can make use of partial views for your Data Entry header section and Data entry footer section

Comment: I prefer to use `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()` helper for rendering header and footer sections - with corresponding partial views for each section.

Comment: I am surprised that no one have solution of my question

Comment: the people who commented on this question above have essentially handed you the solution... separate common pieces of markup into partial views and include the partial views on whatever pages are necessary